# how do I reference a text box value in an expression? SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reference, textbox

I have a list and inside this list I have a text box.

Since it's a list, the text box value changes for each row in the dataset.

OUTSIDE this list, I have another text box which is part of the HEADER.

I want the HEADER to change based on the value of the text box in the list.

In the text box in the header, how do I reference the text box inside the list?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

To refer to any report objects you can use ReportItems Collection.

In your header textbox put a expression like this to refer to textbox in the list:

```
=ReportItems!TextBoxList1.Value
```

Remember SSRS is **case sensitive**. Make sure you get the right name of the text box object you are referring to.

[MSDN article on ReportItems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255285.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It helped me today :)

Comment: Is there a way to reference the current text box? Other than to look up its name and identify it explicitly, I mean.